# How do I differentiate style for last element in .map

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

First off, let me leave the codesandbox for this problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-ben-ttosvh?file=/src/Letter.js:358-389).

I am mapping through an array of letters.

```
const letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
```

The idea is for all of the letters except the last one to have an arrow below it pointing to the next letter. How can I accomplish this?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      {letters.map((letter, index) => (
        <Letter key={index} letter={letter} />
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

```
const Letter = ({ letter }) => {
  return (
    <Box
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Text>{letter}</Text>
      <ArrowDownIcon />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Currently, I am getting what's pictured below. I need to figure out how to remove the last arrow (the one below 'F').

[image]

I tried applying `_last={{ display: "none" }}` to the ArrowDownIcon but this just removed all of the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You could take CSS pseudo class [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).

Comment: How would I use this pseudo selector with Chakra UI?

Comment: @JevonCochran, sorry i have no idea of chakra ui.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a prop to the `Letter` component which checks whether each element is the last or not and render the icon conditionally using the same prop.

```js
import { Box, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { ArrowDownIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons'

const Letter = ({ letter, isLast }) => {
  return (
    <Box
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Text>{letter}</Text>
      {!isLast && <ArrowDownIcon />}
    </Box>
  )
}

export const App = () => {
  const letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
  return (
    <Box mt={10}>
      {letters.map((letter, index) => (
        <Letter
          key={index}
          isLast={index + 1 === letters.length}
          letter={letter}
        />
      ))}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Comment: exactly something i was about to write.